# What free responsive theme I can use for build my responsive Magento theme?

Tags: magento, themes

all. I need free responsive Magento theme for build my custom theme. What can you advice to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antony,Can please used the below-http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mobile-shoppe-a-responsive-theme-by-creative-glance.html

Comment: Cool, it's looking great. I will choose this theme. Thanks, Amit

Comment: You can find full suit of Best Free Magento Themes [http://www.magikcommerce.com/magento/themes/free-themes/] for your eCommerce store. All these top free Magento themes can be easily tweaked and customized for the needs of your eCommerce store.